# circle changes position suddenly with a or w movement on the first click

Tags: javascript

I have a circle that I want to move with WASD. So far I've got it to work but the first A or W movement changes the circle position suddenly instead of smoothly (you'll see what I mean in the jsfiddle). When I press D (or S) instead of A it launches the circle into nowhere. After 1 press of both A and W it works as intended. I would need someone who can fix the sudden movement for it to become smoother, thanks.

note: Try to keep it as simple as possible (if you can do that), so I can understand it with minor difficulty.

https://jsfiddle.net/CarelessInternet/vkau9085/ (ignore the colors)

HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="circle"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Some** of the JS Code (please see jsfiddle for all of the code):

```
var up = false,
down = false,
left = false,
right = false,
x = document.getElementById("circle").style.left,
y = document.getElementById("circle").style.top,
div = document.getElementById("circle");

document.addEventListener('keydown', press);
function press(e) {
if (e.which == 87) {
up = true;
} else if (e.which == 65) {
left = true;
} else if (e.which == 83) {
down = true;
} else if (e.which == 68) {
right = true;
}
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', release);
function release(i) {
if (i.which == 87) {
up = false;
} else if (i.which == 65) {
left = false;
} else if (i.which == 83) {
down = false;
} else if (i.which == 68) {
right = false;
}
}
```

**Some** of the CSS Code:

```
#circle {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 5px solid white;
background-color: black;
position: fixed;
left: 220px;
top: 125px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try console logging the values of x and y immediately after you declare them, and you'll see the problem: they are not numbers. They are empty strings, which when coerced into numbers are converted to 0. So your intial `x - 5`, for instance, returns -5. That's because `HTMLElement.style` only gives you the *inline style* values, not the values computed from a CSS style sheet.

To get the computed style, you'd use `window.getComputedStyle`; this still returns a string such as "220px", so you then need to convert to a number with parseFloat:

```
var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("circle")),
x = parseFloat(computedStyle.left),
y = parseFloat(computedStyle.top);
```